# Programmatically download embbeded dynamic-generated PDFs

Tags: php, python, pdf, download

I know the question may be old but I'm doing it again because I didn't find any satisfactory solution.

I have to download embbeded pdf files from a remote webserver. The problem is that the embbed src is not the direct path to the file, but instead something like this:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://www.example.com/getPdfPage.do?page=10" type="application/pdf" mytubeprocessed="Y">
```

So basically you have to pass the page as argument and the .do file returns the pdf embedded
My question is: how do I programatically download the PDFs without having to click the Reader's "Floppy Disk" icon? If its possible...

EDIT: I can use PHP and/or Python

Comment: put up a separate `<a href="http://yadayada?page=10&mode=download">click here to save</a>` link which triggers a download header on your pdf generator, so it outputs a `content-disposition: attachment`-type header.

Comment: `requests.get("http://www.example.com/getPdfPage.do?page=10")`? Or there is some constraint missing from your question. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to ask? Perhaps you can say what you have tried so far, or perhaps even post a short program that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Also, are you asking a question about Python or PHP? You've tagged both, but mentioned neither in your question.

Comment: Opening the link directly in the browser or using get only returns me HTML code containing another <embed> with the PDF. In other words, it returns me HTML and not a real PDF file. Despite looking promising "mode=download" didn't work also. The pdf generator is not mine. Its from a remote server and I don't know if this "mode" type even exists

Heres the actual link as an example: [PDF](http://www.dje.tjsp.jus.br/cdje/getPaginaDoDiario.do?cdVolume=8&nuDiario=1708&cdCaderno=13&nuSeqpagina=2500)